# Do all objects we see emit light which then forms an image inside our eye?

Tags: optics, visible-light, everyday-life, geometric-optics, vision

Daily life we see so many objects .Often in textbooks the ray diagram for the image formation in eye is shown by showing light rays coming from the object and making an image in inner layer of eye . Do all objects and surroundings emit light so as we can be able to see those things when they make an image inside the eye ? If this is not true then what is the exact reason we see most objects at day , is tubelight in home / sun outside a reason for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the things you see are not emitting light. Usually they are reflecting light from light sources, and this reflected light is what you see. Typical light sources that do emit light in everyday life are the sun outside and light bulbs inside.

Comment: Understood the ray diagrams got me confused , thanks for clearing it